# php push notification APNS sandbox

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I use a self written script to send push notifications to APNS with PHP. I'm trying to get the response from the sandbox and I always get 0. This is suppose the mean that the push was a success but I still get 0 even when a intentionally cause an error. If a make a typo in the deviceToken, I should get error = 8 but stil get 0.

The thing is this it's he first time I use the sandbox to test the push and I'm wondering if the sandbox really send the notification or simply push it to something like dev/null...

Here's some of the code that I use:

```
public function sendMessage($deviceToken, $message)
{
    $streamContext = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', self::APNSCERT);

    $apns = $this->_connectSocket($streamContext);

    $payload = array();
    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => utf8_encode($message), 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
    $payload = json_encode($payload);

    $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    $success=0;
    $retry=0;
    while($success==0 && $retry<=3)
    {
        if (!@fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage))
        {
        var_dumd($this->_error.)
        var_dump($this->_errorString);

           $apns = $this->_connectSocket($streamContext);
           ++$retry;
        }
        else
        {
            $success=1;
        }
    }
    usleep(2);
    fclose($apns);
}

protected function _connectSocket($streamContext)
{
    if (!$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://'.self::APNSHOST.':'.self::APNSPORT, $this->_error, $this->_errorString, 5, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext))
    {
        var_dumd($this->_error.)
        var_dump($this->_errorString);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return $apns;
}
```

last edit: code formatting correction

Answer (score 2):

Change second function
**//Try this function, I did something similar**

```
protected function _connectSocket($streamContext)
{
if (!$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://'.self::APNSHOST.':'.self::APNSPORT,
 $this->_error, $this->_errorString, 5, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext))
     {
         exit("Failed to connect: $this->_error $this->_errorString" . PHP_EOL);
     }
else
     {
         echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
         return $apns;
     }
}
```

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable